# Why do some programmers declare variables like my $myvariable = shift; in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have been following the tutorials on perlmeme.org and some of the authors declare variables in following way:

```
my $num_disks = shift || 9; # - no idea what the shift does
```

and within loops like

```
my $source = shift;
my $dest = shift;
my $how_many = shift;
```

when you use

```
print Dumper ( $source );
```

the result is undef

Why can you not just use

```
my $num_disks = 9;
my $source;
my $dest;
my $how_many;
```

to declare the variables?

Comment: I guess the first step is to find out what `shift` does in Perl?  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html

Comment: Then you are missing that by default `shift` operates on `@_`, which is where subs store their arguments. It pops arguments off the arg list. The `||` operator is used to set a default if the arglist has no more args.

Comment: @DanLowe why use `my $num_disks = shift || 9;` outside of an array

Comment: @BenWhite `@_` *is* an array.

Comment: @DanLowe: "Then you are missing that by default `shift` operates on `@_`". Pedantically, that's only true within a subroutine. Outside of a subroutine, `shift` works on `@ARGV` by default.

Comment: To get the documentation for any Perl function, type `perldoc -f functionname`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`shift` is a function that takes an array, removes the first element of it and returns that element. If the array is empty, it returns `undef`. If shift gets no arguments, then it automatically works on the `@_` array when inside subroutine (otherwise it uses `@ARGV`).

Arguments to functions are placed in the array `@_`.

So if we write a function that takes two arguments, we can use shift twice to put them into variables:

```
sub add {
    my $a = shift;
    my $b = shift;
    return $a + $b;
}
```

And now add(3,4) would return 7.

The notation

```
my $a = shift || 1;
```

is simply a logical or. This says that if the result of `shift` is falsy (undef,  zero, or empty string for instance) then use the value 1. So that's a common way of giving defaults to function arguments.

```
my $a = shift // 1;
```

is similar to previous example but it assigns default value only when `shift()` returns `undef`.

Comment: Ah great, I missed the fact that @_ contains the arguments to a function

Comment: _result of `shift` is falsy (undef, **zero**, or empty string for instance)_, I think zero should not be there because if we pass `0` in subroutine add, it will take it as `0` and return `4`.

Comment: But don't use _$a_ and _$b_ as function arguments anyway, it's reserved for [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function. :)